# Find the font-family for multiple websites using a crawler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I'm looking to find the font-family used for a specific element (like h1) on a given page. I'm using node js [npm crawler](https://www.npmjs.org/package/crawler) to go through an list of 50 or more sites. In my first attempt I used:

```
$( "h1" ).css( "font-family" );
```

However this will only get inline styles which most sites don't use for fonts. I have looked into other methods like [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element) but these methods (and similar ones) use window and document which I don't think are supported in node. They also might use id and class to select the elements which I will not have as I will be crawling multiple sites.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to achieve this.